# How to divide values amongst same column in a table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in following format:

```
CompID Value
155    10
156    20
158    30
```

I have to calculate it as `155+156/158` i.e., `10+20/30`

How can I calculate this using a `SQL` query?

Comment: What's the logic? why 155+156 / 158 and not 158+155/156?\

Comment: actually I need to calculate a metric which is having components as 155,156,158 and the formula to do that is 155+156/158

Comment: how do you identify from the table which records are suppose to add together and which to divide ?